# Can't install QGIS 1.7.4/1.8 after system update

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, installation

After a routine system update my QGIS got lost (xubuntu 12.04). After trying to reinstall 1.7.4 this message appears in Softwarecenter (German):

```
Die folgenden Pakete haben nicht erfüllte Abhängigkeiten:

qgis: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) aber 2.15-0ubuntu10 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) aber 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libgsl0ldbl (>= 1.9) aber 1.15+dfsg-1build1 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libpq5 (>= 8.4~) aber 9.1.3-2 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) aber 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) aber 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libqt4-svg (>= 4:4.5.3) aber 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) aber 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) aber 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.6.1) aber 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36) aber 2.2.1-1ubuntu4 soll installiert werden
      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) aber 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 soll installiert werden
      Depends: qgis-providers (= 1.7.4-1~oneiric1) aber 1.7.4-1~oneiric1 soll installiert werden
      Depends: qgis-common (= 1.7.4-1~oneiric1) aber 1.9.90+git20120511+6678c75~precise1 soll installiert werden
```

After trying to install QGIS in terminal, that appears:

```
root@MAP-PC:~# apt-get install qgis
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 qgis : Hängt ab von: qgis-providers (= 1.7.4-1~oneiric1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
        Hängt ab von: qgis-common (= 1.7.4-1~oneiric1) aber 1.9.90+git20120511+6678c75~precise1 soll installiert werden
        Empfiehlt: qgis-plugin-grass soll aber nicht installiert werden
        Empfiehlt: python-qgis soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
root@MAP-PC:~#
```

Seems, some dependencies are missing, but that makes no sense for me! The same happened with qgis-masters.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: Did you uninstall 1.8 before trying to reinstall 1.7.4, Martin? I'm not sure it's a good idea to have both installed at the same time (it caused problems for me). Nick.

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled it before.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem: I had to totaly remove my old qgis 1.9 (aptitude), and change the software source to:

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main
```

(did the source-path change in the last days?)